# ffmpeg decode multiple streams at same time

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to decode a file and play it back on an android device.  I have this working and would now like to decode two streams at the same time.  I have read some comments regarding needing to use av_lockmgr_register() call with ffmpeg, unfortunately I am not sure how to use these and how the flow would work when using these locks.

Currently I have seperate threads on the java side making requests through JNI to native code that is communicating with ffmpeg.

Do the threads need to be on the native(NDK) side, or can I manage them on the java side?  And do I need to do any locking, and if so how does that work with ffmpeg?

***UPDATE
I have this working now, it appears that setting up the threads at the java sdk level transfers into separate threads at the native level.  With that I was able to create a struct with my variables, and then pass a variable to the native layer to specify what struct to use for each video.  So for I have needed to use any mutexs or locks at the native level, and haven't had any issues.

Does anyone know of potential gotchas I may encounter by not doing so with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this, my latest update approach appears to be working.  By controlling the threads from the java layer and making my native calls on separate threads everything is working and I have not encountered any issues.